# Jetty SSL not working. Accessing website gives unreadable output

Tags: ssl, https, jetty, embedded-jetty

EDIT: Self-signed certificate installed on browser made it work.

I have configured jetty 9 embedded for http on port 8080 and https on port 8443. When I visit localhost:8080 I get my website and everything works, but when I try to access localhost:8443, I get this mess: [image of unreadable stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGx0F.png).

I pretty much mimicked the [ManyConnectorsExample](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyConnectors.html) in the jetty documentation in order to set up a http connector and a https connector. Here is my code:

```
File keystoreFile = new File("config/myownkeystore.p12");
    if (!keystoreFile.exists()){
        throw new FileNotFoundException(keystoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    Server server = new Server();

    HttpConfiguration http_config = new HttpConfiguration();
    http_config.setSecureScheme("https");
    http_config.setSecurePort(8443);
    http_config.setOutputBufferSize(32768);

    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server,
            new HttpConnectionFactory(http_config));
    http.setPort(8080);
    http.setIdleTimeout(30000);

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreType("PKCS12");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(keystoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("myownstorepass");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("myownkeypass");


    HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration(http_config);
    SecureRequestCustomizer src = new SecureRequestCustomizer();
    src.setStsMaxAge(2000);
    src.setStsIncludeSubDomains(true);
    https_config.addCustomizer(src);

    ServerConnector https = new ServerConnector(server,
        new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));
    https.setPort(8443);
    https.setIdleTimeout(500000);

    // Set the connectors
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { http, https });

    // servlet handler
    ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    servletContextHandler.setResourceBase(".");
    servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
    servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MainServlet()), "/*");

    // set the handlers
    HandlerCollection handlerList = new HandlerCollection();
    handlerList.setHandlers(new Handler[]{servletContextHandler});
    server.setHandler(handlerList);
```

At first I thought that maybe the keystore type was at fault, since jetty uses jks by default. So I switched the sslcontext to use pkcs12 since the keystore is a .p12 file. That didn't help.

I checked the passwords next but the password for both private key and for the keystore are the same, so that can't be the issue.

At this point, I want to believe its a fault in my code somewhere, but I don't know what is wrong exactly.

Comment: Just copy/pasted your code into my IDE.  It works fine with Java 8u91 and jetty-9.3.11.v20160721.  The only things I did on top of what you pasted: created a MainServlet, used my own keystore & keystore passwords (I also don't use PKCS12 certificates).

Comment: I just generated a new JKS with a new key pair to see if that would help, but it didn't. Do I need to install the public certificate to my browser maybe? Yeah that seemed to be the case. I'm dumb.